# Portrait Photograph, How do I get this

Tags: print-design, inkscape, photography, portrait

I am trying to achieve the runny ink look below on a portrait of a girl I took yesterday. At first I thought this look was the result of an error in the development process, but seeing other versions of the original image leads me to believe it was done in photoshop.

I want it to look like the image below, if you could point me in the right direction, i would greatly appreciate it.

[image: Portrait]

This ![][2]

Comment: Hi sam, welcome to GDSE and thanks for your question. Could you tell us what you tried that didn't work? Always good to show some effort, and your chances for a good answer increase. If you have any questions, please see the [help center](http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/help) or ping one of us in [chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/1240/the-ink-spot) once your reputation is sufficient (20). Keep contributing and enjoy the site!

Answer (score 1):

Here's what I would do:
Find a runny stain as well as some grain texture.

Work this first in black and white...You might want to calibrate levels on your source images so they merge together better. Use masks to merge the running stain to the portrait and use layer modes for the texture (e.g. Multiply).

Using an extra layer on top of it all and layer modes (possibly colorize) color over everything with a fairly big, blurry, low opacity brush at first and work your way into more detailed areas. You might want to sample the colors of the original portrait or use different colors but use the same palette over both the face and the stain so they seem to connect.